# haproxy absolute redirect for an entire domain

Tags: haproxy

I have been googling for hours with no luck for something that has got to be simple.

I am using haproxy 1.7 and am attempting a 301 redirect for all traffic from one domain to another "landing page" with partial success. I can get a basic redirect to work, however if someone uses a bookmarked link for example, they will get a 404, since the URL does not exist on the new domain.

domain1.com/foo or domain1.com/bar/baz/whatever all need to get redirected without exception to domain2.com/landing  I cannot find an acl in any examples on how to do this.  I know it has got to be some kind of rewrite rule before the reidrect, but I cannot get one to work.

Here is some of the settings I have tried:

```
#        reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /(.*)  \1\ /\2 if domain1_host
#        redirect location https://domain2.com/landing  code 301  prefix /landing drop-query if domain1_host
#        http-request replace-header X-REWRITE ^/.*?$ /\1 if domain1_host
#        reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)(.*) \1landing\2 if domain1_host
#        reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)[/]?(.*)     \1\2 if domain1_host
#        reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /(.*) \1\ /\2 if domain1_host
#        redirect prefix https://domain2.com/landing code 301  if domain1_host
redirect scheme https://domain2.com/landing code 301  if domain1_host
```

If anyone has some suggestions on what I have missed, I would really appreciate some direction.

Answer (score 2):

Fighting with this and finally found an answer.  I was right, it was simple.  No reqrep, or rewrites outside of the redirect rule were needed.  Simple redirect location to the destination location.  It is an absolute rewrite.

```
redirect location https://domain2.com/landing code 301 if domain1_host
```

was all that was needed.

I wish there was a better example on the web for when redirect location would be useful, but I suspect most people are going to need acl's or redirect prefix more often than redirects like this.   My hope is that someone else in the future looking will find this post useful however.